# What's the difference between a forms library vs. the central admin page where you manage form templates in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I was wondering in sharepoint what the difference between a forms library in sharepoint vs the central admin page under manage form templates.  I am trying to upload .xsn files so that no one can access them, but I don't know if I should upload them to the central admin page or if a forms library will suffice.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big differences with deploying through Central Admin are:

- admin deployment only (though you've already figured this one out)
- form versioning is available
- may be made available to all site collections at the discretion of the admin
- when you deploy a form, it deploys as a content type
- are intended for forms that contain code (other than the inline stuff) - a form in a form library cannot contain code

You can also deploy an InfoPath form to a content type, so that it can be available to a site collection.

To use forms deployed through Central Admin, you'd create a new form library, then allow management of content types for the form library and configure the library for this content type.